# How to do something when your contract is an action notification recipient (like when it receives funds)?

Tags: action, transfer

The EOSIO_ABI macro seems to only forward actions meant for our contract. How do you also listen to all other contract actions (like the very common transfer action for the account "eosio.token")?

I tried not using the EOSIO_ABI macro and just use the C code, but then the .abi generation doesn't work anymore. So what's the best implementation to listen to all actions for all contracts while still being able to use the eosio toolset (which includes .abi creation)?

**EDIT: I just talked to Daniel Larimer himself on Telegram and adding a better way to handle actions for other contracts is planned after june. Right now apparently it can only be done by sacrificing auto generation for .abi files with the eosiocpp toolset.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extend EOSIO_ABI macro to handle eosio.token transfer notification.
Please pay attention to if statements:

```
if( code == self || **code == N(eosio.token)** || action == N(onerror) )  
DO NOT USE THIS CODE ABOVE ANYMORE, OR YOU WILL BE ATTACKED!
```

```
if( ((code == self  && action != N(transfer) ) || (code == N(eosio.token) && action == N(transfer)) || action == N(onerror)) )
```

```
// extend from EOSIO_ABI
#define EOSIO_ABI_EX( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
extern "C" { \
   void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) { \
      auto self = receiver; \
      if( action == N(onerror)) { \
         /* onerror is only valid if it is for the "eosio" code account and authorized by "eosio"'s "active permission */ \
         eosio_assert(code == N(eosio), "onerror action's are only valid from the \"eosio\" system account"); \
      } \
      if( ((code == self && action != N(transfer)) || (code == N(eosio.token) && action == N(transfer)) || action == N(onerror)) ) { \
         TYPE thiscontract( self ); \
         switch( action ) { \
            EOSIO_API( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
         } \
         /* does not allow destructor of thiscontract to run: eosio_exit(0); */ \
      } \
   } \
}

EOSIO_ABI_EX(eosio::charity, (hi)(transfer))
```

Comment: still the same problem (the .abi file has no actions after using eoscpp to generate it). Does it work for you? Where do I have to put that macro? Do I need to use a .hpp file or should it work with just a .cpp file?

Comment: you should add a structure same name with action function and put annotation //@abi action before it.     // @abi action
    struct hi {
      account_name user;
    };

Comment: .hpp/.cpp  are the same.

Comment: Yes they were already in place. Just when I replace the normal EOSIO_ABI macro with your implementation (or any other implementation of the pure C code), the .abi doesn't contain actions anymore after creating it with eosiocpp, so I get errors when pushing the actions to the blockchain. Did you test the macro and does it keep your other actions operational?

Comment: After some more testing in a blank project it's become apparent that @abi action isn't even required for some reason. As long as I use the EOSIO_ABI macro, eosiocpp -g automatically generated the actions in the .abi. Anyway, i'm still not closer to listening to other contract actions. You'd imagine that handling incoming transfers is one of the main features of a smart contract, but I still haven't been able to find how to do it in Dawn 4.0+ anywhere online.

Comment: call  require_recipient( account);  will send action to the account contract. and then you can extend EOSIO_ABI to handle the action notification in your code.    The EOSIO_ABI will not impact the result of abi generation.

Comment: Thanks @ofo your solution worked nicely for me: https://gist.github.com/leordev/c927cd919f3a84be368b2bc5e2aee883 -- The only downside is the abi generation, as @PunchPlump said `@abi action` does not work anymore.

Comment: maybe many contracts use your code, and be attacked

Comment: maybe ...T.T  improvement:  if( ((code == self && action != N(transfer)) || (code == N(eosio.token) && action == N(transfer)) || action == N(onerror)) )

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to redefine EOSIO_ABI macro. @ofo's solution is correct for the code generation part but to make auto abi generation work EOSIO_ABI macro has to be used. To do this you first undefine macro and than define it again:

`#undef EOSIO_ABI`

`#define EOSIO_ABI(TYPE, MEMBERS) \
   ....`