# How to perform something when my contract receives a eosio.token transfer notification?

Tags: transactions, action

I know a very similar question has been asked here ([How to do something when your contract is an action notification recipient (like when it receives funds)?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-to-do-something-when-your-contract-is-an-action-notification-recipient-like)), however I don't have enough reputation to ask a follow up question to that answer, so I open a new question.

As mentioned in that answer, extending the EOSIO_ABI macro with a statement like "if( code == self || code == N(eosio.token) || action == N(onerror) )" can trigger the "transfer" function in your contract when a eosio.token transfer notification is received. However, what if I already have another function named "transfer" with a different purpose? How can I map the eosio.token transfer notification to a function that has a different name?

Comment: can't understand, can you speak Chinese?

Answer (score 1):

Create a transfer action and a transfer_b action in the contract. Call tranfer_b as an inline action in the transfer action.

Do not change 'apply' and use it as macro generated it.

Use 'SEND_INLINE_ACTION' when calling 'transfer_b' in an inline action with a transfer action.

For an example of this, see the issue action of the following code.
https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/EOSIO/eos/-/blob/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp#L32:65

Answer (score 0):

code is the contract processing the message, action is which action is called. these two condition is enough to identify which transfer is used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I understand how to identify which contract the action is from, however I don't understand how to call the action that has a different name from the original action. Say I want to call an action named transfer_b when I receive a transfer notification from eosio.token, I believe I need to modify the "MEMBERS" in "switch( action ) {EOSIO_API( TYPE, MEMBERS)}" in the macro, however I just have no idea how to modify it, I couldn't find any documentation about these macros.

Comment: if(code == N(eosio.token) && action == N(transfer)) {you call trasnfer_b}