# Is it safe to assume that a function can't be called directly if it is not defined in the ABI?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions

I'm writing a function in my contract that is supposed to run only if I receive a transfer notification from "eosio.token". The way I handle eosio.token transfer notification is similar to [this](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-to-do-something-when-your-contract-is-an-action-notification-recipient-like/431#431) (but not exactly, I changed the condition so that my function will be called ONLY when the "code" is "eosio.token"). My function is a public function but it is not defined in the ABI file.

My question is: Is it safe to assume a user has no way to call this function except through pushing a transfer action with "eosio.token"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contracts can't call each others' functions. Instead, they send actions to each other. All actions go through the `apply` function; it determines what's accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense! I think I can achieve what I want by making sure my function won't be called except when "code" is "eosio.token" and "action" is "transfer" within the "apply" function.

Comment: Yes. That works.